# Move django website from one server to another

Tags: django

I have a django website on a webserver and I want to change hosting service, how can i move the django website to the new server? And how can I make sure that it works the same? 
I am using SQLite Database so that shouldn be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'll need to find a way to move your source code (and in that case the database as well) to the new server. ftp, git...
2. Assure that you have all the project dependencies installed on the new server
3. Test it

Would be nice if you try to migrate first and come again with the eventual problems that you face.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try that! Oh and btw can you recommend any hosting service?